# ODE solution existence and uniqueness

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, initial-value-problems

my question is: can i apply the theorem I mentioned in the title to assert that there is only a solution(given initial conditions) to a energy conservation equation?

I'm talking about an equation like this:

$ E= m \dot x^2 + kx $

My doubts come from the fact that the equation isn't linear, but I can obtain a form like this:

$ \dot x = \pm \sqrt{ f(x)} $

So we have two equations that singularly seem to respect the hypotesis of the theorem cited, but I'm not sure they do that when together.

Comment: I suppose that you're referring to Picard theorem. Take a look at the Picard theorem for the solution of the Cauchy problem involving ODEs https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Picard%E2%80%93Lindel%C3%B6f_theorem

Comment: Yea I know the theorem, I m not sure if my problem verifies the hypotesis

Answer (score 1):

No, your problem $\dot{x} = \pm\sqrt{f(x)}$ doesn't satisfy the assumpitons of the theorem, because $\pm\sqrt{f(x)}$ is not even a function, while Picard's theorem deals with problems

$\dot{x}(t) = F(x(t),t)\quad , \qquad x(t_0) = x_0$

where $F(x(t),t)$ is a function that, beyond being a function, must be continuous in $t$, and Lischitz-continuous in $x$.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you could apply the Picard-Lindelöf theorem directly, as your expression looks like $\dot x=\sqrt{E-kx}$ and fails to be defined for its entire domain (square root of a negative number).

What you instead would want to do in a physics class is to apply the Picard-Lindelöf theorem to the [Hamilton’s equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamiltonian_mechanics) for the energy expression, that should be more tractable.

Comment: So mathematically there is no way, given a energy differential equation, to know if the solution, if it exists, is unique?

Answer (score 0):

As long as the initial condition is such that $E-kx_0>0$ then the Cauchy-Lipschitz theorem does appply and so you can assert that there exists a unique solution to the ODE defined for $t$ close to $t_0$, providing two (local) solutions of the energy conservation equation. The solutions should also be explicitely computable, no ?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: So like merging two solutions, one for each sign?

Comment: Let $x_0$ be a number such that $E-kx_0>0$. Any solution of the energy conservation equation such that $x(t_0)=x_0$ will satisfy $E-k x(t)>0$ for $t$ close to $t_0$. Now, this gives rise to two distinct solutions of two distinct ODEs satisfying the hypothesis of the Cauchy-Lipschitz theorem. In addition, these solutions should be explicitly computable by separation of variables.  Whether these solutions can be merged at a time $t$ s.t. $E-kx(t)=0$ (and so the uniqueness in the Cauchy-Lipschitz theorem no longer holds) is a problem that can also be decided by direct computation.

Answer (score 0):

The equation
$$
2E=m\dot x^2+kx^2
$$
can be locally uniquely solved for $\dot x$ if $\dot x\ne 0$. This local explicit form is then also continuously differentiable under this restriction. This gives monotonic solution segments.

It also has constant solutions at $\dot x=0$, that is, at $x=\pm\sqrt{2E/k}$. At these constant solutions there is no Lipschitz condition, the derivative is unbounded around it. More, one can easily construct piecewise solutions that alternate monotonous and constant segments.

Only by requiring that the second derivative be continuous one gets the "physical" solutions.